# React.js unable to load file from public folder in production

Tags: reactjs, three.js

Here i am loading my glb file in react typescript project

```
useGLTF.preload("/Doggo07.glb");
```

In production it is not working. I am amplify to deploy to prod. But, it is saying not found
there. Doggo07.glb is available inside my public folder.

Please let me know know can i access in production build from public folder.